# Handbrake encoded MP4 won't play on iPad via VideoJS

Tags: ipad, video, video.js

I have a 'very' simple web page I've thrown together using VideoJS to playback an MP4. This works a treat with desktop browsers and also on the iPhone but fails to load/play on the iPad. Instead I just get a solid black rectangle. I'm completely baffled - any ideas?

http://haslams.net/sandbox

I'm guessing it could possibly be an encoding issue but I'm suprised that it plays back just fine on the iPhone but not the iPad. Both devices have the latest iOS install (5.1.1).

:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your link, none of the [Video.js setup methods](http://videojs.com/docs/setup/) are being used, so basically Video.js isn't running. Add data-setup="{}" as an attribute to the video tag. I'm not sure if that will fix the issue, but it's a start.